# When program uses Command to open Bash to run a script, Bash closes immediately without running the script

Tags: windows, bash, command-prompt, git-bash

I have a simple, already-working bash script set up to launch specific files with specific programs in the gaming frontend EmulationStation on Windows.

But the frontend routes its actions through a Command Prompt. And when Command is used to run the script through Bash, the Bash shell just opens and then closes immediately.

[Here's an image of what shows for the instant before Bash closes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGk35.jpg)

This is only happening when going through a separate Command Prompt first, such as Windows Command Prompt or Git Command Prompt. Running the script with an appropriate argument directly through the git-bash shell works just fine.

In case you want to see the script for any reason, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

defaultemulaunch="V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/systems/retroarch/retroarch.exe -L "V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/systems/retroarch/cores/bsnes_mercury_accuracy_libretro.dll" \"$1\""

emu1names=(\
    "(1999) Fire Emblem - Thracia 776.smc")

emu1launch="V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/systems/retroarch/retroarch.exe -L "V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/systems/retroarch/cores/snes9x_libretro.dll" \"$1\""

gamename=`basename "$1"`
for index in ${!emu1names[*]}
    do
        game=${emu1names[index]}
        if [ "$game" == "$gamename" ]; then
        eval "$emu1launch"
    fi
done

eval "$defaultemulaunch"
```

But it's worth pointing out that this is happening when trying to run *any* bash script when starting the process from a separate Command Prompt.

**Note:** Git is installed on the hard drive that houses the emulation frontend (V:)---not in the user directory or programs directory of the system's OS/boot drive (C:). I mention this because git-bash's failure at an apparent "login" step except when launched directly feels like it could be a default filepath issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if that program would still open/close a Windows when executed from the CMD with:

```
bash -c '/v/path/to/bash/script'
```

In your case:

```
set PATH=V:\Emulation\
set GIT_HOME=V:\Emulation\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH
```

Then:

```
cd V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/roms/snes/
bash -c './gamelaunch.sh "./(1990) F-Zero.sfc"'
```

I usually make a `run.bat` script which would:

- set the correct `PATH`
- launch the correct script

That way, for any of my project, I just type run.
And it runs.

Comment: It does not open and close a window in that situation; trying that instead causes Command to return a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: @precursormar What command do you type in that CMD? For a bash program, I would type (and have done so many time) `bash -c "./my_bash_script_file"`

Comment: When it opens and close immediately, I am just typing in something like:

````V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/roms/snes/gamelaunch.sh "V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/roms/snes/(1990) F-Zero.sfc"````

Windows associates .sh files with git-bash, so it attempts to run the script with git-bash, but then the Bash shell closes.

When I type any variant of ````bash -c "/v/Emulation/.emulationstation/roms/snes/gamelaunch.sh"````,

I get back:

````/bin/bash:```` [filepath]````: No such file or directory````

Comment: The only situation that results in the script doing what it's supposed to do is by opening git-bash.exe directly, and running a command like ````V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/roms/snes/gamelaunch.sh "V:/Emulation/.emulationstation/roms/snes/(1990) F-Zero.sfc"````

Comment: @precursormar TRy the same `bash -c "..."` in a CMD where you set first a simplified PATH, as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57345422/6309.

Comment: Okay, I've just tried ````set PATH=V:\Emulation\````, ````set GIT_HOME=V:\Emulation\Git````, and ````set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%````. Then I ran the same command. This time nothing happened at all: no error message, and no window pop-up. Did I set the PATH variable incorrectly?

Comment: @precursormar PATH looks good. I don't know what command you typed though. I would cd to the right folder, and type `bash -c "./my_bash_script_file"`, with `./` meaning look for the script in the current folder.

Comment: Okay, that worked! After settings those temporary variable changes and navigating to any part of the V:, the script properly executes with the command ````bash -c './gamelaunch.sh "./(1990) F-Zero.sfc"'```` Does that mean I should permanently add those PATH parameters to fix this?

Comment: @precursormar Great! Well done. See my edited answer: I prefer using a wrapper instead of modifying the PATH at a global Windows level.

Comment: That works! Thank you very much for your assistance! But you'll need to edit the ````"./gamelaunch.sh "./(1990) F-Zero.sfc"```` to ````'./gamelaunch.sh "./(1990) F-Zero.sfc"'```` in your example, otherwise the quotation marks cause a syntax error. (I was going to make the edit myself, but Stack Overflow won't let me because it's less than 6 characters of change.)

Comment: @precursormar You are most welcome. I have edited the command accordingly.