# Git Portable - WARNING terminal is not fully functional

Tags: git

Certain commands, such as `git log` result in an annoying error message before the expected output is produced on screen.  The error message looks like this:

```
C:\CNC>git log
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
- (press RETURN)commit 5d2076175b...
```

Now let me differentiate this question from similar questions and show what I've already tried.

- I'm using git portable on Windows; version 2.22.0.windows.1
- Windows 10, Version 10.17763
- I'm not using git-bash and for the sake of this question, assume it is not possible.  I am specifically asking for a solution with git-cmd.exe.
- I do not have admin access on my machine.  Other questions have people setting an environment variable `set TERM=msys`.  I can do this under my user profile, but not at the system level.  I have set TERM at the user level, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only use the Git portable edition, and do not see this issue.

```
vonc@VONCA D:\git
> git version
git version 2.21.0.windows.1
```

[I did recommended `set TERM=msys` in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25337788/6309), but that should not be needed nowadays (2019).

Check if the issue persists when using Git in a simplified PATH in your regular CMD session:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

git log
```

[`git-for-windows/git` issue 1572](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1572#issuecomment-377373971) mentions:

> The warning message is not from `git`, but from `less`, which is used as the default pager by `git`.
>
> If you specify `less -d` as `pager`, less will not warn about your terminal:

```
$ less --help | grep -A 1 dumb
  -d  ........  --dumb
                  Dumb terminal.
```

> You can configure this with: `git config --global core.pager "less -d"`
>
> you can also use: `git config --global core.pager "TERM=cygwin less"`.
>   This will give you a more functional pager.
>
> Yet another solution is to create a batch file:
>
> ```
> $ cat less.bat
> @set TERM=
> @less.exe %*
> ```
>
> And use it as your pager:
>
> ```
> git config --global core.pager "/c/path/to/batch/less.bat".
> ```

Comment: Still happening with simplified PATH variable.

Comment: @scottmwyant Is this a regular CMD or an emulator like Cmder? And maybe Windows 10 17763 is a bit old. I use a 1903, build 18362.

Comment: Plain old CMD. Yes, unfortunately, I was just upgraded from Win7 to 10 two months ago...

Comment: @scottmwyant At work then. I understand, I use a Windows 10 1710 at work too. But I don't have this issue. Can you list somewhere your environment variables, with `set`?

Comment: @scottmwyant I see your simplified path is missing mingw64\bin (which I forgot). Can you retry with `C:\...\git\mingw64\bin`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197444/discussion-between-scottmwyant-and-vonc).

Comment: excellent!  What worked for me is the `git config --global core.pager "less -d"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, upgrade my old **Windows 7** desktop to **Windows 10**, and found out `TERM` system variable had been added by Strawberry Perl and set to `dumb` decades ago.

So remove the `TERM` system variable from Windows 10 `environment variables` settings fix this issue without any further updates.

Now, type `echo $TERM` shown the default value: `xterm-256color` works for everything...