# It' s possible to works SSH and git command in gitlab-ci?

Tags: shell, ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In my gitlab-ci.yml, I have an SSH connection to another server, all my command are working except the git commands

They block the script with the message:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

and my script is blocked

My code in gitlab-ci :

```
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - ssh  -tt root@1IP 'cd PATH; git branch;docker run  -it -v $PWD:PATH -w /PATH cypress/included:6.5.0 | tee  result.txt'
```

Without the git command, it's work.

Of course, in my remote server, git branch work's fine.

Any ideas ?

Thanks :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an error message coming from [`less`, used as a pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) by Git, [as I documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57345422/6309).

Try:

```
 git config --global core.pager "less -d"; git branch; ... (rest of the commands)
```

The `-d` option (from [`less` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html)) option suppresses the error message normally displayed if the terminal is dumb;